# Unfilled form values creating empty rows in mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, field

First time poster, long time lurker :)
I have a form setup that posts data for multiple rows in a single table with seven colums to a php function to insert it as new records in a database. The form is working great, however, if one of the rows in the form is left unfilled then the php function is creating a blank row in the database. I am attempting to figure out how to avoid this. I am certain it has nothing to do with the form itself, and rather has to do with the php. Please have a look at it. I'm totally open to suggestions.

```
<?php
require("header.php");
require("dbinc.php");
foreach($_POST['card'] as $row=>$cardcounted) 
{
    $model=$_POST['model'];
    $serial=$_POST['serial'][$row];
    $card=$cardcounted;
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO receivers (`id`, `model`, `serial`, `card`, `status`, `date`, `location`) VALUES ('null','$model','$serial','$card','$status','$date','$location')");

    if(!isset($serial[$row]) || $serial[$row] == '') {
        // error message here, redisplay form if desired
    } else {
        // no errors - process data
    } 

    if (!$query)
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
echo $row+1 . " record(s) added";

mysql_close()
?>
```

I added in the !isset on the serial numbers by row to check for null posts but am unsure as to how to incorporate that properly. i think im on the right track, just need that little push :)

Comment: It's 2011 - your code is *so* wide open to SQL injection attacks that it's not even funny. Use prepared statements and PDO.

Comment: Fourth or fifth time I mention this topic today: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First choice is to use JavaScript validation to find out invalid form submits, Some users may disable JavaScript, so its always recommended to do server-side validations

So write a method like

```
isValid($postArray) {
  foreach($postArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == "") {
       return false;    
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If form field names and db column names are similar you can use

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO receivers ";
$keys = "(";
$values = "(";
foreach($postArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != "") {
       $keys += $key;
       $values += $value;
    }
}

$sql = $sql + $keys +" VALUES "+ $values;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try moving your mysql query into your `else` currently you insert values into the database regardless of whether you have form errors or not. Also you will need to secure anything that you are inserting into your database. Its an SQL injection field trip right now ;)

Comment: yeah i know :) its on a private offline network for in-building use. just something im literally throwing together for personal use.

Comment: Yep, in internal tools it's okay to get a crash if you type `you're`.

Comment: @Alvaro - Stressful day huh :P Let it out fella, let it out!